# 'jQuery' is undefined Jquery jquery-ui-dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery.ui.dialog.js to show the modal pop up..
But this Jquery.ui.dialog.js is throwing a javascript error 'jQuery' is undefined.
Please help .
How can i resolve this.
I am using this two .css and .js

1.jquery.ui.dialog.css & 1.jquery.ui.dialog.js
2.jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css & query-ui-1.8.2.custom.js

Please advice.

Comment: Maybe you should google first or search the site for similar questions. 90% chance that you just didn't include the jquery lib itself.

Comment: show us code between <head> .... </head>, u r probably missing something or path is not correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you ensured that your  tag for jQuery comes before the same for jQuery UI?

Beginners guide is here:

http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included the jquery-1.4.2.js file in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the jQuery library itself to use jQuery UI, make sure to download and include that script as well from [the jquery.com download section](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) (also make sure it's beofre all other jQuery dependencies, plugins, UI, etc).

Or, include it from a CDN like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```